# How to sync .ackrc and .gitignore_global?

Tags: gitignore, ack

I find that the file/directory types in my .gitignore_global (which changes fairly regularly) are typically those that I'd like to ignore in my ack searches.

Is there a way to sync or "pipe" the the ignored files / directories from my .gitignore_global to my .ackrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: I now use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) for this type of thing.

---

Recently found [Ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (a.k.a. the silver searcher) and [git-grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep), both of which serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

ack does not currently look at `.gitignore`, but we have plans to allow for plugins in the future and that will be one of the first ones we do.